# Can't update the zoomScale of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, swift-playground

I'm trying to assign `newScale` to `zoomScale` of a UIScrollView if `zoomScale == oldScale`, and the assignment `zoomScale = newScale` doesn't work.

Here's the test code in my playground.

```
import UIKit

let scrollView = UIScrollView()
let contentView = UIView()

scrollView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(200, 200)
contentView.frame.size = CGSizeMake(400, 400)

var zoomScale: CGFloat {
    get { return scrollView.zoomScale }
    set { scrollView.zoomScale = newValue }
}

var minimumZoomScale: CGFloat {
    get { return scrollView.minimumZoomScale }
    set { scrollView.minimumZoomScale = newValue }
}

func updateMinimumZoomScale(withScale newScale: CGFloat) {
    let oldScale = minimumZoomScale
    minimumZoomScale = newScale

    if zoomScale == oldScale {
        // zoomScale = 1, newScale = 0.1 //
        zoomScale = newScale
        zoomScale == newScale   // false
    }
}

updateMinimumZoomScale(withScale: 0.1)
```

And here's a screenshot of the result.

[image: Screenshot of the playground result]

In the screenshot, the result of `zoomScale == newScale` is `false` right after the assignment `zoomScale = newScale`.

I have really no idea why this is happening.

Comment: I tried to play with your code but it seems to me that you can't modify the zoomScale (or at least the change is not effective) until the scrollView is in the view hierarchy. Have you tried the same code in an actual Xcode project and in the simulator ?

Comment: In fact this problem was first found in my project. I just extract relevant code into playground.

Comment: I'm having the same problem after converting to Swift 3. My delegate is set properly and has been working up until this point.

Comment: It's a weird bug. After I reinstalled my Mac or Xcode (can't remember now) this problem was solved. And I cannot tell whether it's a bug of Xcode or a bug of my Mac. I think it's probably Xcode. So I suggest you may try another version of Xcode (maybe beta version) and see if this is solved. @JustinVallely

Answer (score 3):

Even i tried out your code in playground and actual project but it didn't seem to work. Problem is you need to set delegate for your scroll view before setting zoom scale. Delegate is set this way

```
scrollView.delegate = self
```

When you try to set zoom scale for scroll view `-viewForZoomingInScrollView` method is called, and if your delegate is nil then that method won't be called. Hence it won't set zoom scale. You can try same sample in Xcode project with setting delegate before changing zoom scale and it will work.

Comment: In my project, I set the view hierarchy and the delegate to self correctly. The most strange thing is, why a simple assignment operation would do nothing on these two value-type variables. So, what do you have of the line `zoomScale == newScale`, are they equal to each other?

Comment: By doing `zoomScale = newScale` you try to set zoom scale of scroll view(that's what you are doing in setter). But since you didn't set delegate zoomScale will not change and continue to be 1. Hence they are not equal.

Comment: I re-installed Xcode and now I think this problem is solved. Anyway, thank you:)

Comment: I am having the same problem, with delegate set properly.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was with the Xcode auto-conversion to Swift 3. The delegate was set properly, but the delegate methods weren't properly formatted.

Comment: Hey Justin, I am also stuck at this issue. Can you tell me how you have set the delegate and its callback functions with sample code? I have set the delegate to my class but no delegate callback is received.

Comment: @Payal, I just removed the underscore that the Xcode auto-converted added to the first parameter.